# Changing a image on the source code of an existing website

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my HTML skills and I'm trying to change an image from the source code of an existing website and replace it with an image from my computer.

I linked the .html and the .css documents and when I open the .html file on my browser I see all the images of the original website but when I put my .jpg images instead I have blank spaces instead.
For instance:

```
<img src="/images/fullscreen/name_of_the_original_file.jpg" alt="" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-bgparallax="10" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>
```

-> I see the original image

```
<img src="/my_directory/name_of_my_image.jpg" alt="" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" data-bgparallax="10" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>
```

-> I see a blank space

Can you help me out ?

Comment: It's not finding your picture because it's looking for it on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images served via websites are handled by **servers** rather than clients. When you visit a website, you are actually viewing a **cached** copy of it, unique to you. The caching occurs so that when you attempt to view the same page again, you don't need to download the images again, using up your data in the process.

This can be a confusing concept, as website like Facebook and Twitter make use of [**AJAX**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to update the content you see without you needing to interact with the site. Note that this sort of behaviour simply **retrieves** more up-to-date information from a server by simply 'refreshing' your cached copy.

You **cannot** modify the server-side code unless you actually **own** the website, as that would be a huge security vulnerability. Imagine if you had a public page that listed User A's information. User B could come along and change it to their own information. User A would want to see their own information, not User B's.

The above sort of issue is resolved by making use of a **database**. Both User A and User B have their relative information stored in a database, and the page can simply serve the desired content with a conditional query, depending on the information that you want to display. For example, `SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER = 1` or `SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USER = 2` (in [**MySQL**](https://www.mysql.com/) syntax).

If you **do** own the website you're attempting to modify, you have two options:

1. Modify the files directly through a hosting platform (typically **[cPanel](https://cpanel.com)**).
2. Modify the files locally, and then upload them via [**FTP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol).

Obviously, method 2 is preferred, so that your local copy is always up-to-date with the server.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is server-side oriented.
The existing website is being hosted on some server, so all the files, including html and css files are uploaded to the server using some client. 
For example, if you have your live website, and you edit some code on your computer, you need to upload those edited files on to your server, for example using FileZilla or something like that, it depends.